# 6 Stepper Motors at 3000 Steps Per Second

Tags: gpio

I am planning on purchasing 6 stepper motors that I will need to operate at roughly 3000 steps per second each with DRV8825 stepper drivers.

I was wondering if the Raspberry Pi 3B+ has the speed to update GPIO pins to STEP the driver at that speed. I wanted to use JAVA or Python.

I haven't purchased anything yet. I wanted to see if it is possible first.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you can toggle the GPIO that fast in Python and probably Java.  Doesn't help though, does it?.  How are you going to distribute those pulses to your steppers in a controlled way?

Comment: Thanks! Yeah that will be a little tricky. I am making a Stewart-Gough Platform vibrate sinusoidally with six steppers. I will have to pre-calculate the path and get the timings right before I move. It would take too much time to calculate while running. Do you have any advice?